# Derivative of polynomial function

Tags: calculus, polynomials

$$f(x) = 2x - \frac{1}{4} x^2$$

How could I know calculate with limits the derivative of this function when $x_0 = -4$?
I started already like this:

$$f'(-4) = \lim_{x\to-4} (2x-\frac{1}{4}x^2-4)/???$$

Comment: Do you mean $2x-\frac{1}{4}x^2$?  It reads like $2x-\frac{1}{4x^2}$

Comment: you forgot to divide by $x-a$... And then all you need to do is...divide...

Comment: Not quite, you also have $f(-4)= -4$, so when you subtract $f(-4)$, you need to add $4$.

Comment: @Thomas: Are you sure? $2(-4) - (1/4)(-4)^2 = -8 - (1/4)(16) = -8-4=-12$.

Comment: Whoops, you're right @ArturoMagidin, but it still makes his $-4$ wrong.

Comment: @Thomas: Oh, absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition:
$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}.$$
Here, 
$$f(x) = 2x - \frac{1}{4}x^2,$$
and so
$$f(-4) = 2(-4) - \frac{1}{4}(-4)^2 = -8 - \frac{1}{4}(16) = -8-4 =-12.$$
Plugging everything into the general formula,
$$f'(-4) = \lim_{x\to -4}\frac{f(x)-f(-4)}{x-(-4)} = \lim_{x\to -4}\frac{(2x-\frac{1}{4}x^2) - (-12)}{x+4} = \lim_{x\to -4}\frac{2x - \frac{1}{4}x^2 + 12}{x+4}.$$
Can you take it from here?